# Is this possible to set a modifiedDate for a particular revision?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am currently working on drive sdk revision upload . I can able to upload the revisions by using "NewRevision=true" , But i cant able to set a modified date for that .

```
$boundary = mt_rand();
$curl->setHeader("Host", "www.googleapis.com");
$curl->setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $new_accesstoken");
$curl->setHeader("User-Agent", "CXchange-CXchange-1.0 cURL/1.11.3");
$curl->setHeader("Accept-encoding", "identity");
$curl->setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"');
$content = '';
$content = '--' . $boundary . '
          Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

          {"modifiedDate": "' . $rev[ 'modifiedDate' ] . '"}
          --' . $boundary . '
         Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
         ' . $revison_content . '
         --' . $boundary . '--';
$curl->setHeader('content-length', strlen($content));
$rev_uploadUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/' . $newFileId . '?uploadType=multipart&newRevision=true&convert=true';
$curl->put($rev_uploadUrl, $content);
```

It return successful message, But when i go to Google Drive UI and try to see the revions list in right side pane the modified time not updated as i given

Please help me to overcome this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `setModifiedDate=true` in the query string.

Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update